# Windows 10 Idle Disk Usage

Tags: windows, hard-drive

Every time I leave the keyboard and mouse untouched for a minute, my CPU jumps to about 15% and one or another disk drive jumps to 100% usage.  As soon as I press a key or move the mouse it stops.   If I let it continue, it runs the drive for about 5 minutes, then does the same thing to another drive. and then another, and so on.

I  opened Resource Monitor and Task Manager, and found the following:

The program responsible is ntoskrnl.exe

It always starts by constantly writing to many files in the same subfolder of the \System Volume Information\ of my F: drive, a non-system 1TB HDD data drive that I rarely use.

I have attached a highlighted screenshot to show what I mean.

[ResMon and Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV9QG.png)

The subfolder has two codes in it, {702cb035-a9a5-11ed-ae78-2c4dSAeffc8a} and
{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cC752}.  Google gave me nothing for the former but a lot on the latter.
Most of the suggestions I read either didn't seem like it would fix the problem, and/or seemed like they might hobble my computer.

Two things I have tried:

I disabled the Volume Shadow Copy service.

I turned off indexing on the drive.
Neither had any effect.

I also checked the drive's SMART status.  Green across the board.

I have had this HDD for a long time and I am concerned that chronic disk usage like this will cause it to fail sooner than it ordinarily would.  It also bothers me when the computer is doing something I don't understand and can't control.

How can I turn off this constant idle disk usage?

Comment: It can be many things, I'm thinking at Windows telemetry services, Cortana, diskperf... But please allow Volume Shadow, it can help. If you didn't do it, get (free) [OOSu10](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10) (apply green carefully) or [PrivacyTweaker](https://www.majorgeeks.com/mg/getmirror/windows_privacy_tweaker,1.html) (easier) and get rid of all Telemetry first!

Comment: It could either be a virus scanner or defragmentation process.  Type in Optimize in the task bar and select. it.  Click on Change Settings and see what the scheduler is set to.